# Laravel model without primary key and datastamples

Tags: php, laravel, model

I have an issue regarding Laravel's model.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Offices extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = null;
    public $incrementing = false;
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

that's my model. When i try to query it doing like so:

```
$office = Offices::where('worker_id', '=', $worker->id)->first();
```

I receive a weird error

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `offices` set `visit_called_id` = 125 where `` is null)
```

What am I missing? I think I've included all the code that was supposed to make it work :/

Comment: You cannot have a table in a relational database without a primary key.  In addition laravel does not support composite primary keys. Do yourself a favour and add an incrementing `id` column

Comment: what is the relationship between worker and office table in ur database?

Comment: I dont want to have incrementing id column since it's supposed to be just one record for each worker_id

Comment: There is no declared relationship.

Comment: So primary key is `worker_id` ?

Comment: I suppose it can be

Comment: Then set `protected $primaryKey = "worker_id";`

Comment: That's a great answer. Thank you

Comment: The error you're receiving is related to an update statement, however the code you've posted is a simple select.